# Request fallida, error 500 en petición a plataforma EcuadorLis

Tags: python

El siguiente código es una solicitud de secuencia de comandos, pero siempre devuelve el error 500 y no sé por qué. Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda.

quiero extraer información de la plataforma, pero siempre que ejecuto el script me genera un error 500 y no me funciona.

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'JSESSIONID': 'K23+csupxfNn6S+2Fvi+V1mP.89271ce5-ef4e-3789-9164-9f731c92d21b',
}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,es-ES;q=0.8,es;q=0.7',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    # 'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=K23+csupxfNn6S+2Fvi+V1mP.89271ce5-ef4e-3789-9164-9f731c92d21b',
    'Origin': 'https://www.senescyt.gob.ec',
    'Referer': 'https://www.senescyt.gob.ec/consulta-titulos-web/faces/vista/consulta/consulta.xhtml;jsessionid=wQ4aVqwH3+dZ-3Xarm36-EQg.89271ce5-ef4e-3789-9164-9f731c92d21b',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
}

data = {
    'formPrincipal': 'formPrincipal',
    'formPrincipal:apellidos': 'Herrrera Rodguez',
    'formPrincipal:identificacion': '',
    'formPrincipal:captchaSellerInput': 'exap',
    'formPrincipal:boton-buscar': '',
    'javax.faces.ViewState': '1844354123356586311:-2962370977458019807',
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://www.senescyt.gob.ec/consulta-titulos-web/faces/vista/consulta/consulta.xhtml',
    cookies=cookies,
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
)
```